# React tailwind headless ui, Menu onColse action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, headless-ui

on tailwind ui, I am using Menu. I want to add some action to close the Menu, But I am not getting any option to add a custom action to close the menu.

```
      <Menu
         as="div"
         className="relative inline-block text-left"
       >
     {({ open, close  }) => (
       <>
        <Menu.Button className="inline-flex w-full items-center justify-center gap-x-1.5 bg-white text-sm font-semibold text-gray-200 ring-1 ring-white-200 py-1 px-3 rounded shadow-md">
          Filter
        </Menu.Button>
        <Transition
          show={open}
          as={Fragment}
          enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
          enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
          enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
          leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
          leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
          leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
        >
          <Menu.Items
            static
            className="absolute mt-1 right-0 z-10 w-100 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white shadow-md focus:outline-none"
          >
            <p>Some action</p>
          </Menu.Items>
        </Transition>
      </>
    }}
  </Menu>
```

I want to add some action when I close the menu clicking outside of the menu.

Comment: It's unclear to me! Do you want to "close the menu" manually or "perform an action when the menu is closed"?

Comment: you can explain both. Yes, I want to perform some action.